# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'meanmenu'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a responsive menu to work.  I can't see why it can't find meanmenu.  Could someone please look at this with a fresh eye?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php get_theme_url(); ?>/assets/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        "use strict";
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('.menubox').meanmenu(); 
        });
    });
</script>
<script src="<?php get_theme_url(); ?>/assets/js/jquery.meanmenu.js"></script>
```

Comment: what does return by `php get_theme_url();?` I think it's need to `echo`

Comment: It is the path to the file

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your custom plugin before using it:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php get_theme_url(); ?>/assets/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="<?php get_theme_url(); ?>/assets/js/jquery.meanmenu.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        "use strict";
        jQuery('.menubox').meanmenu(); 
    });
</script>
```

Also, you just need to use DOM ready handler once `jQuery(document).ready(function(){...});`

Comment: This is obviously a good thing to do, but the OP's code almost certainly *didn't* use the plugin before loading it, as the OP's code waited for the `ready` callback.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Isn't it possible that the DOM is ready before the script is loaded?

Comment: @Scimonster: With the quoted markup, only if the entire thing being shown is being loaded via `.load` or similar. If the quoted markup is just in the main page (as it most likely is), no, `ready` won't fire until after the final script has been downloaded and executed, because the script tags don't have the `defer` or `async` attribute.

Comment: @user3398974 Please check the browser console. It's probably because of the path of your file.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'meanmenu' (index):41
(anonymous function) (index):41
o jquery.js:2
p.fireWith jquery.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.js:2
c.addEventListener.B

Comment: @user3398974 Please check again if the path to your `meanmenu` is correct. Try to use `<?php echo get_theme_url(); ?>` instead of `<?php get_theme_url(); ?>`